# Prevent method from showing up in Stack Traces

Tags: .net, clr, stack-trace

Using the .NET CLR, is there a way to prevent a certain method to show up in the stack trace? Especially I just want to remove the last call from the stack trace before throwing an exception.

I'm just curious, unsafe calls and reflection hacks are valid solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's your `Exception` implementation, you can override [`StackTrace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.stacktrace%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) to return whatever you like. And the [this constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ws7f30w6.aspx) of the `StackFrame` class makes it easy to create a stack trace whilst skipping any number of methods.